# Boilsoft Video Splitter - Keep Subtitles and Audio Format

Tags: video-editing

I have a H.265/HEVC video with two FLAC audio tracks and subtitles. How do I use Boilsoft Video Splitter to split it with frame accuracy while preserving all audio tracks as they are and keeping the subtitles?